# Alternatives to onhashchange?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, webkit, window

I've got an `onhashchange` like so...

`window.addEventListener("hashchange", afunction() , false);`

which calls a function on hash change.. the problem is the function itself inserts a `div` into the page. This seems to cause the function to infinite loop re-calling itself over and over. Is there anyway I can modify my call so that it will not do this? and only change it if the rest of the page changes? Each time the rest of the page changes I want to update my div. The page is changing via AJAX and I'm using the rest of the page to construct my div so I must wait on till it finishes regenerating.

Comment: What is the code of `afunction()` then? I currently cannot see what could be the cause of the re-calling.

Comment: Inserting a `div` does not trigger the `hashchange` event. Only changing the hash triggers it. For an answer you need to provide the code of `afunction`. I'm pretty much sure that your code should be `window.addEventListener("hashchange", afunction , false);` (note the missing parenthesis after the functions name).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", afunction() , false);
```

It is saying take whatever `afunction` returns and assign it to this event.

You want to say assign a reference to `afunction`, that means you do not want the ()

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", afunction , false);
```

Comment: You're almost certainly right, but I'm always little frustrated by this answer. OP does not show the code of `aFunction` so we don't know what it does. If it returns a function then your answer is completely wrong. The correct answer to OP's question, then, is that not enough info was provided to give an answer.

Comment: The answer as it stands is 100% wrong. It claims that `afunction()` is an invalid second argument to `addEventListener` which is simply not true.